# Numpy Masking with a multidimensional list of indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have arrays

```
data = np.array([[0.75, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2],
                 [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]])

labels = np.array([3,1])
```

How can I overlay the indices over the data such that I get this result?

```
np.array([0.2, 0.3])
```

In other words the index of the `labels` array matches with the `data` array and the value for each indices corresponds with which index value to take from the row in the `data` array.

I have been trying to find an efficient way to do this so preferably something vectorized and simpler to understand if such a method exists.

Comment: Can you give us a better example and explanation.  There are four .2's in the array, so it's not clear at all which one you've pulled or why.

Comment: ok I edited the arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to index in 2D.

```
>>> data[np.arange(len(labels)), labels]
array([0.2, 0.3])
```

Comment: Just curious, but I was confused conceptually why data[:, labels] does not do the same thing as data[np.arange(len(labels)), labels], I thought the : would just give all the indices but instead the output shape is different

Comment: @kazar4 I'm actually not sure! I'm pretty new to NumPy myself. It's described in the docs [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing), but I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the indexing method mentioned by @wjandrea, its easy to see that the items you want will lie at the diagonal of the indexed matrix `data[:,labels]`, or `data.T[labels]`.

So try this -

```
data[:,labels].diagonal()

#OR

data.T[labels].diagonal()
```

```
array([0.2, 0.3])
```

Another way you can do this is by using `np.take_along_axis` which lets you pick specific indexes along an axis. In this case, that axis is 0. But you will have to reshape your labels to have 1 label per row.

```
np.take_along_axis(data, labels[:,None], axis=1)
```

```
array([[0.2],
       [0.3]])
```

This you can then transpose or use flatten by using `output.ravel()`